# Check if ContentDocumentLink is link to note

Tags: apex, trigger

How to check if ContentDocumentLink is link to Note in Apex trigger?

Comment: What trigger be that? You can check if `ContentDocument.FileType = 'SNOTE'`

Comment: thanks @zaitsman it's right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @zaitsman said correct answer is ContentDocument.FileType == 'SNOTE'